# Grails 2.0.1: Spock test fail with "No bean named 'grailsLinkGenerator' is defined" where redirect is called

Tags: testing, grails-2.0, spock

I recently upgraded from Grails 1.3.7 to Grails 2.0.1. The application runs normal, but I get into this trouble when cleaning up tests.

All my tests are spock tests. And I updated spock from 0.5-groovy-1.7 to 0.6 when upgrading.

All controller tests that will reach a line of redirect() fail in that line with the same error:

```
No bean named 'grailsLinkGenerator' is defined
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'grailsLinkGenerator' is defined
```

Any idea what cause this and how I could fix them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This started happening for me in a controller unit test by extending spock's ControllerSpec.  Switching it back to extend spock.lang.Specification fixed it.

The Spec:

```
package fileupload2

import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat
import static org.hamcrest.core.Is.is

import spock.lang.Specification;

import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import grails.plugin.spock.ControllerSpec

@TestFor(FileUploadController)
//class FileUploadControllerSpec extends ControllerSpec {
class FileUploadControllerSpec extends Specification {

    def "the index should redirect to create" () {

        when:
            controller.index()

        then:
            assertThat(response.redirectedUrl, is('/fileUpload/create'))
    }

}
```

The CUT:

```
package fileupload2

class FileUploadController {

    def fileUploadService

    def index() {
        redirect (action: "create")
    }

    def create() {
        render(view: 'create')
    }

    def upload() {
        ... 
    }

}
```

I'm reluctant to say this is a bug as I'm about 2 weeks into this.

Extending UnitSpec seems to work also.